# ImportError for folders as modules: "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, relative-import

My folder structure looks like below

```
.
└── myfolder/
    └── mock/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
    └── common/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── db.py
        └── routers
            └── myroute.py
            └── __init__.py
```

My main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from ..common.db import create_db_and_tables
from ..common.routers import myroute


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(myroute.router)
```

Now from inside of `mock` if I run the `main.py`, I am getting `python ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` .

I am not sure whats I am missing here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: I did try running with `python -m main.py`  inside `mock` . But getting same error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/407651

Comment: @Dibshare please have a look at the answers provided (at least at the accepted ones), btw. `python -m main.py` does not  make any sense.

Comment: Yes , i got a sense of the issue , import same modules from root is working fine. Just trying to figure out what it takes to run it from inside that `mock` folder

Comment: I find the posted answers in the comments way too complex and too long! Option a) add the path of myfolder (including myfolder) to the environment variable PYTHONPATH. Option b) add import sys and sys.path.append(r"../../myfolder") as first lines in main.py